# "Southernmost point in" vs. "southernmost point of"

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, prepositions

Which of the following is correct? Or are they both wrong?

> - The southernmost point **in** Ohio.
> - The southernmost point **of** Ohio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with the general consensus that they are roughly the same.  However, it's probably more mathematically correct to use *of* to refer to multiple subsets, and *in* to refer to a single set.  For example:

> The southernmost point **in** the state of Ohio.
>
> The southernmost point **of** *all the counties* in Ohio.

Answer (score 1):

Both are technically correct, although the point of reference is slightly different.

In the statement:

> The southernmost point of Ohio.

We're referring to the state's bottom portion, a singular dot on a map.  Nothing else generally.

In the first statement:

> the southernmost point in Ohio.

At this point you'd usually be referencing a place like a field or range of some kind, basically whatever is in the southernmost area.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, Jacob.  I'm talking about a specific place.  The complete (albeit fictitious) statement is:

Hilton Head Island, the southernmost point of Ohio.

Thanks again.

Comment: A specific place? So you're looking for something like, "The ranch is located in the valley at the southernmost point in Ohio."?

Comment: So you're saying that it should be:

Hilton Head Island, the southernmost point in Ohio.

Got it.  Thank you so much.

Comment: @Stephen Legg: If that solves your question please accept the answer.  It rewards the person who gave the answer and informs the community that the answer is now closed.  Plus it's good for the statistics :)

Comment: @Jacob: Accepting an answer doesn't mean an "answer is now closed," it simply means an O.P. has selected an answer. Other users can still answer the question; moreover, an O.P. can change accepted answers, if a later contribution does a better job of answering the question. That said, it is true that fewer people may bother to look at a question if an answer has already been accepted; that's why I think it's a good practice to wait at least half a day or so before accepting an answer, so as not to discourage others from weighing in.

Comment: I'm new to this forum.  What does O.P. mean?  Also, where do I accept the answer?  Is that the button on the bottom that says "Answer Your Question"?  I didn't know that was a question but I will click it if that is what you would like.  Thanks.

Comment: O.P. or OP refers to the "original poster".  In this case, that's you.  To accept a question you click on the checkmark beneath the vote up and vote down buttons on the left side of the question.

Comment: got it. thx again